# Spring Batch - Split a read line FlatFileItemReader into multiple lines while writing

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Spring Batch -  How can I Split a read line (FlatFileItemReader) into multiple lines while writing using FlatFileItemWriter ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need an [`ItemProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/whatsNew.html#whatsNewItemProcessor) to convert the object created from the single line (let's call that `YourInObject`) to a `List<YourOutObject>`.

However, I don't think Spring Batch supports such a One-To-Many approach out of the box, so my guess is you will have to create a custom `ItemWriter<List<YourOutObject>>` that delegates the individual objects to `FlatFileItemWriter<YourOutObject>` (You can find examples of delegating writers in the link below).

**Reference:**

- [Chapter 6. ItemReaders and
  ItemWriters](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html)